# Laravel - Unable to retrieve data stored in session after coming from payment gateway

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.5

I have a noob question.
After filling a form I store data in a session and redirect users to a payment website to pay, after which I return them to my site to complete registration.
The problem is I get the undefined variable error when I'm redirected back to the site where I try to pull the data stored in session. 
I've checked my session.php it is set to 'expire_on_close' => false,

The session bit of my controller is the standard $request->session()->put('user', $user);

So my question is his how do I get my form data from session after leaving and returning back to my site?

Comment: Are you sure you're returning to the exact same scheme (`http` / `https`), hostname and port? Is your session cookie configured under a specific path?

Comment: Yea I'm sure of the scheme because my site is on localhost. Woah! It seems session is configured to a specific path. Any idea how to undo that? Controller maybe

Comment: could you check on your `config/session.php`? is it perhaps the `domain` part is wrongly configured?

Comment: @Umar745 see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#configuration. The configuration is in the [session.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.5.28/config/session.php#L141) file

Comment: @bagus-tesa  'domain' => env(SESSION_DOMAIN', null),  session cookie path => '/'.  Also session driver is file, should I maybe change it to cookie?

Comment: I've been making a real novice mistake. I just realised that I need to do $user =$request->session()->get('user'); in the controller of any page I want the session data to appear. Thanks guys

Comment: whoops, we also missed that. glad you fixed it.